# NSURLConnection redirect pause

Tags: iphone, redirect, nsurlconnection, sleep

I currently have a NSURLConnection to a site that does a bunch of redirects

```
  NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
  if (theConnection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
  }
```

I would like pause in between the redirects without pausing the main thread, as I do now. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
{
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
  return inRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCD:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
               dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  /* Your code */
}];
```